# texture font not carrying over

Tags: game-engine

Ok so I have two files A.blend and Z.blend

Z.blend has a plane with a textured font on it...you know one of those fontname.tga files right. Start up Z.blend and it all works perfectly.

Now for A.blend, in this file I created a mesh cube that has the following logic:

**Keyboard** -> **And** -> **Game**: Start Game From File

So when the character walks up to the cube and presses the letter "T" for example it'll switch A.blend to Z.blend.

Now here's where my problem lies...

Once the switch has been made from A.blend to Z.blend and you go through the blend file the plane containing the fontname.tga is black as if it can't find the .tga file or texture.

Any idea on how to get the texture to show up?

Answer (score 1):

Safe a .tga file in the same location as the A.blend and Z.blend file.

1. Go to the location where A.blend and Z.blend is saved.
2. Create new folder call it "texture"
3. drop .tga file in the texture folder.

To recap if your A.blend and Z.blend file is in E:\mesh\
then your texture must be found in E:\mesh\texture\

**A second solution** would be to pack the image file inside the blend file.
In your case Z.blend needs to have a packed copy of the .tga in question.

[image]

That was how blender game makers pack all their textures, when they ship their game out for others to download for play testing. In this way the client will
always have all the texture require for the game to look good.

Hope that helps.